Reusing an output in Falstad
I'm simulating a logic circuit in Falstad and a particular output X is used multiple times in the circuit. Can I take input as X without drawing many wires from X?

You can use a labelled node (Draw » Outputs and Labels » Add Labeled Node)
to reference any node in the circuit from multiple places.
See example: Falstad circuit

Thank u so much :)
